# 64-bit installation of Ubuntu doesn't recognize more than 2.9GB of RAM

Tags: ram

My BIOS recognizes 4GB, Ubuntu 13.10 only sees 2.9GB. I'm running an ASRock FM2A75 Pro4-M motherboard, 4GB of some generic RAM, and an AMD A6-5400K.

I've updated to kernel 3.12.3, no change.

The output of uname-m

```
x86_64
```

Output of free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2962       1159       1803          0         28        318
-/+ buffers/cache:        812       2150
Swap:         3905          0       3905
```

output of sudo lshw

```
description: Desktop Computer
product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be     Filled By O.E.M. uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
  *-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: FM2A75 Pro4-M
   vendor: ASRock
   physical id: 0
   serial: E80-2B019800452
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: P1.80
      date: 11/02/2012
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 8128KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 9
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: EBJ21UE8BDF0-DJ-F
         vendor: Elpida
         physical id: 0
         serial: E0973A4A
         slot: A1_DIMM0
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM [empty]
         product: Array1_PartNumber1
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
         physical id: 1
         serial: A1_SerNum1
         slot: A1_DIMM1
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: EBJ20UF8BCF0-DJ-F
         vendor: Elpida
         physical id: 2
         serial: E037024F
         slot: A1_DIMM2
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM [empty]
         product: Array1_PartNumber3
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer3
         physical id: 3
         serial: A1_SerNum3
         slot: A1_DIMM3
 *-cache:0
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 14
      slot: L1 CACHE
      size: 96KiB
      capacity: 96KiB
      clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
      capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
 *-cache:1
      description: L2 cache
      physical id: 15
      slot: L2 CACHE
      size: 1MiB
      capacity: 1MiB
      clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
      capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 1f
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
      slot: CPUSocket
      size: 2400MHz
      capacity: 3600MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1 cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fd000000-fe0fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GK107 [GeForce GTX 650]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
            resources: irq:18 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fe000000-fe07ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: GK107 HDMI Audio Controller
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
            version: a1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:19 memory:fe080000-fe083fff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 10
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe106000-fe107fff
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 10.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.1
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:17 memory:fe104000-fe105fff
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
         resources: irq:47 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f050(size=16) memory:fe10d000-fe10d7ff
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 12
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe10c000-fe10cfff
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 12.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fe10b000-fe10b0ff
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 13
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe10a000-fe10afff
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 13.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fe109000-fe1090ff
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: FCH SMBus Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 14
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-ide
         description: IDE interface
         product: FCH IDE Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master
         configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=32
         resources: irq:17 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:f000(size=16)
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: FCH Azalia Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:fe100000-fe103fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: FCH LPC Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: FCH PCI Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master vga_palette
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe108000-fe108fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 15
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 15.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) ioport:d2100000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 06
            serial: bc:5f:f4:84:c3:5c
            size: 100Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
            resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=k10temp
      resources: irq:0
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD3200BEVT-2
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 11.0
         serial: WD-WXL1A80M8420
         size: 298GiB (320GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000f3392
       *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /boot
            version: 1.0
            serial: 6810c833-a160-44eb-9b2e-9fe6735bcc2e
            size: 237MiB
            capacity: 237MiB
            capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2013-11-24 20:00:12 filesystem=ext4 label=/boot lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2013-12-05 21:43:56 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2013-12-05 21:43:56 state=mounted
       *-volume:1
            description: Linux swap volume
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            version: 1
            serial: be0a87db-5f98-4eac-8a2e-d2fb8679b636
            size: 3906MiB
            capacity: 3906MiB
            capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
       *-volume:2
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: de911bc3-4054-4d43-80c3-8fabf377ace0
            size: 14GiB
            capacity: 14GiB
            capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2013-11-24 20:00:13 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2013-12-05 21:43:56 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2013-12-05 21:43:56 state=mounted
       *-volume:3
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 4
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
            logical name: /dev/sda4
            logical name: /home
            version: 1.0
            serial: cb51e781-5273-4e49-ab44-ce75c7a90754
            size: 279GiB
            capacity: 279GiB
            capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2013-11-24 20:00:15 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2013-12-05 21:44:02 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2013-12-05 21:44:02 state=mounted
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      bus info: usb@2:1
      logical name: scsi3
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         size: 3824MiB (4009MB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=0305a604
       *-volume
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: mkdosfs
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdb1
            version: FAT32
            serial: 69b5-7571
            size: 3822MiB
            capacity: 3823MiB
            capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=HERPADERPAD
```

Comment: please add the output of: uname -m

Comment: Edited it in, doesn't seem like very much

Comment: free -m out put??

Comment: Added, but i don't know how to make it show up as if it were command line.

Comment: its ok , what is the output of lshw

Comment: the output is above

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel still showing 4 gigs of RAM. free only returns map-able RAM. You have 1 Gig of RAM that can not be accessed. This can happen because of several things, but I would guess that the update updated video drivers and that your card is "using" part of that RAM.

You may want to check that your RAM is not "marked bad" with something like [Bad RAM.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM)

Basically you need to figure out where the missing memory is. It's there, your system sees it, it's just mapped to something different then your used to.

answer taken from [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/369103/192102)

Comment: Prior to updating the kernel, running lshw showed that i had 4GB of ram as well. I ran your above code, but nothing happened. If i drop the last part "BIOS..." stuff, then i get an output, but it's jus

Comment: check Bad Ram..

Comment: Interesting.. no memtest option in GRUB.

Comment: i am having memory test option , might be you should consider boot-repair for that , cos some times /boot/default/configuration comments it out ..

Comment: Fixed the memtest issue. I'll run memtest overnight to check for bad RAM. If this is the case, i'm going to return it and get new. Considering i have a 30 day guarantee, and it's been a week.

Comment: I ran memtest, no errors on my RAM. However, I did notice that it was detecting my ram as DDR2, when it is in fact DDR3.

Comment: Thats not the issue because your lshw is showing 4 gigs DDR3 , now the only reason could be your Graphic Card . that might using 1 gigs. How much graphic card you are having.??

Comment: It's not an onboard GPU, and the onboard one is disabled in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after a BIOS flash, that one of my sticks of RAM was dead. Not sure why, but no I can't even get to POST if I leave one of my RAM sticks in.